# Feature Unavailable: Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app, since we are updating additional details for this app

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, fbdev

My app on developers.facebook.com was put into restricted mode when they requested me to send a video of how the login/registration process worked in my app. I submitted that to them and it was resolved. But ever since they put my in restricted and back to live. The login and registration stopped working. And all I get when trying the facebook login is a message:

> Feature Unavailable: Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this
> app, since we are updating additional details for this app. Please try
> again later.

The app is set to **mode Development Live**.

Any ideas?

I have tried to talk with FB but they refuse to understand that it's their changes that has made it stop working. I have not made any changes to the actual app or the "facebook app". So I do not know what changes I can try since I have not changed anything or made any updates. And it all worked before they put it into restricted mode and back to live.

Could this be due to my app not having Business verification? I have tried to set that but I'm unable due to:

> Your business is prohibited from advertising, including app sharing.

And whatever I try, there is no way around this to get the business verified.

Comment: Hi, Were you able to get things working? I started receiving the same problem in December and still can't figure anything out. Here is my post: https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/439628268489919/?post_id=439628271823252